# boolean string not counted in while/if statement in python[3.8]

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, counting

I'm a beginner programmer and chose python[3.8] as my choice to learn.  I don't even know what to ask or how to search this site.  My program counts 30 to 40 and prints 'Go' for multiples of 3 and strings of 3 and remainders of 3. It counts Go's.  Output should be 10 but it's 3. It's not counting the strings.  There is no error msgs.

```
`enter code here`
s = '3'
x = 40
y = 30
num = 0
while y < x :
    y=y+1
    if y % 3 == 0 or y % 10 == 3 or s in 'y' :
        print('Go',y)
        num = num + 1
print(num, 'Go\'s')
```

Comment: Start here: Look at `s in 'y'` - you are looking for '3' in the letter 'y'.

Comment: You should add a tag to your question for the programming language you are using.

Comment: I couldn't add a tag for python[3.8] because my reputation wasn't good enough.  I am trying to look for 3 in the y=y+1 count.  Can you please help?

Comment: If I remove the ' ', I get the following error TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: How does Python convert an integer to a string? You should be able to research that, and solve your problem. You are close.

Comment: Your language is Python - so use that tag.

Comment: If you solve the `or s in 'y' :` part then the rest of your tests are useless. In the range of `30..40` there are exactly ten numbers that *always* fulfil this last condition. The other tests simply don't matter.

Comment: I got it! s in str(y)...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is to understand how **python** works.

When you write `s in 'y'` it will always return false because y here is a character that composes the string which value is `y`the character.

So what you'll need to do is use the function `str(param)` to convert your integer to a string with the same value.
This is a code that works the way you want to.

```
s = '3'
x = 40
y = 30
num = 0
while y < x :
    if y % 3 == 0 or y % 10 == 3 or s in str(y) :
        print('Go',y)
        num = num + 1
    y=y+1
print(num, 'Go\'s')
```

Comment: oh my goodness!  I actually shortened the post for easy understanding.  I modified your code and it works! It works! It works!  Thank you so much....